# version management in microservices

Tags: version-control, cloud, microservices, service-discovery

Suppose that I have a UserService in my **Microservice Architecture** deployed on the cloud. There is a **Service Discovery** for routing the requests to different host of UserService.

If I have two different versions of UserService. Lets say *user-service-1.0* and *user-service-2.0* and part of clients should still use older version, then how this can be managed in Microservice Architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For backward compatibility, see  [Product Versioning Microservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33202053/product-versioning-microservices), in general [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) is advised by many...

In the broader sense - there should be an agreed phase-out roadmap for major versions, that is communicated to API consumers (together with SLAs). This is why tracking who uses your APIs is important.

Answer (score 3):

Every version of UserService needs to be *backwards* and *forwards* compatible. This way clients can talk to any version of the service and not crash.

Of course, the details of how this is achieved depends on your architecture.